# Function returns variable to webpage, variable gets dropped somewhere

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, iis

We have a CMS system in place with url redirection.  For instance when someone surfs to our root https://ourwebsite/ it will be transferred to https://ourwebsite/CMS?Id=62.  This page then check the database for html and outputs this html to the page.

The CMS part is in a different project and our main website has a reference to this project.  It works fine 95% of the time, but then all of a sudden the same call to get a page, for instance id 62 has been working for half a day, but then the same call to fetch 62 would fail.  And from then on it would consequently fail untill we recycle the application pool.

We have been adding debugging to see where it fails.  At first we thought entityframework would suddenly be unable to reach our microsoft sql server.  But further investigation proved this was not the case.  As other entityframework pages would still load, and logging proved he had an object after the call to the database.

The strange thing is, we have a call from the page to our respository, var CMSPage = _repository.GetCMSPageById(62) and just before the last return before we go back to the page we have the desired object in the variable.  (logging showed this)  But after the return to the page the object is null suddenly.  It seems to drop it somewhere between the last return from our repository (in a different dll/project) and the page.

Consequently this ALWAYS happens after an inactive period of our webserver of mostly 20-30 minutes.  So we assume the webserver recycles it's memory and then the calls start to fail.

Example: last night the website was working fine, the last call to CMS page was 01:58:30.  Then no one visited the website till 02:24:00.  The next call to the object he could return at 01:58 suddenly fails.  When further investigating we saw the web server called the onmodelCreating function of EF at 02:23:10.  Coincidence?  Most likely not...  Presumably the web server recycled something or did some garbage collection because of a longer period of inactivity.  And then he starts to fail.  The weird part is, once he fails, he keeps on failing for every CMS requeqt untill app pool recycle and then everything works again.

We are clueless as to where start looking, since it isn't any code that fails, he has an object right before the return to the calling function, and then it's suddenly gone...  Anyone any ideas?

Code example:

In the page load of the page that will handle the cms page request there is this piece of code:

```
Debug.Log($"DustedPreview PageLoad - Get Version By pageversionId: {pageVersionId}");
                    //PageVersion = _domainLogic.GetPageVersionById(pageVersionId);
                    PageVersion = _pageVersionCache.GetPageVersionById(pageVersionId);
                    Debug.Log($"DustedPreview PageLoad - Return PageVersion:(Id:{PageVersion.Id}){PageVersion?.Name ?? "!!ERROR !! PageVersion is NULL"}");
```

I implemented caching, but the problem was already there, and exactly the same before there was any caching at all.
PageVersionCaching is now called, more specific this function

```
public ICMSPageVersion GetPageVersionById(int Id)
    {
        return _pageVersionCache.GetOrCreate(Id, () => _domainLogic.GetPageVersionById(Id));
    }
```

The GetOrCreate simply returns the object from cache if it exists, or creates a new one if it doesn't.  Since the problem was already there before there was caching, and the problem only arises when he needs to re-fetch an item from database, i will Only go into detail to the fetching part.
So my DomainLogic has following code for the fetch: (up until the return there, which returns to the page, i have the complete object like i want it)

```
public ICMSPageVersion GetPageVersionById(int Id)
        {
            var pv = _cmsRepository.GetPageVersionById(Id);
            var dcPv = pv.CreateDcControlledInstance();
            Debug.Log($"CMSDomainLogic - Return PageVersion:(Id:{dcPv.Id}){dcPv?.Name ?? "!!ERROR !! PageVersion is NULL"}");
            return dcPv;
        }
```

The repository in turn has this function:

```
public ICMSPageVersion GetPageVersionById(int Id)
        {
            var proxyCreationEnabled = _ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled;
            _ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var pv = _ctx.CMSPageVersions
                    .Include(x => x.CMSPage)
                    .Include(x => x.CMSPreviewPage)
                    .Include(x => x.CreatedBy)
                    .Include(x => x.ModifiedBy)
                    .Include(x => x.Contents)
                    .Include("CMSPage.CmsTemplate")
                    .Include("CMSPage.CmsTemplate.TemplatePlaceHolders")
                    .Include(x => x.Language)
                    .Include(x => x.State)
                    .SingleOrDefault(q => q.Id == Id);
            _ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;
            var dlPv = FromDto(pv, _cmsFactory.CreatePageVersion());

            return dlPv;
        }
```

Comment: This is hard to answer without seeing code. It may have to do with (EF) context life cycle, but we have no clue.

Comment: Ok, here is a more detailed code example:

Comment: Start by using one context instance per request. That tends to solve state-related problems like this.